# How to close gap at the top of SVG triangle after drawing animation

Tags: css, svg

I am working on a project with a lot of SVG-animation. I have no experience in this. I have Googled extensively without finding the solution to my problem.

The problem is that when animating certain shapes, the animation leaves a gap in the shape. This is most prevalent on shapes with angles, like a triangle.

I have seen this done successfully around the web, I just don't understand how. I have made a simple animation using Vivus Instant that you can see in this CodePen: [Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwdMxa)

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 242.89 367.25" class="start" style=""><title>triangeltest</title><path style="fill:#fff;stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:15px" d="M121.44,23.89L10.38,359.75L232.51,359.75L121.44,23.89Z" class="fTJakOHn_0"></path><style data-made-with="vivus-instant">.fTJakOHn_0{stroke-dasharray:930 932;stroke-dashoffset:931;}.start .fTJakOHn_0{animation:fTJakOHn_draw 3000ms ease-in 0ms forwards;}@keyframes fTJakOHn_draw{100%{stroke-dashoffset:0;}}@keyframes fTJakOHn_fade{0%{stroke-opacity:1;}94.44444444444444%{stroke-opacity:1;}100%{stroke-opacity:0;}}</style></svg>
```

Are there any libraries I can use that automatically avoids this problem? Do I have to export the shapes from Illustrator in a specific way?

Comment: The problem appears on Chrome for anybody (on Firefox) wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is just disable the dash array once the animation completes.

```
@keyframes fTJakOHn_draw {
  99.9% { stroke-dashoffset:0; stroke-dasharray:930 932; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: none; }
}
```

If the animation needs to be able to restart after the fade animation, you might also need to put the dash pattern back afterwards.

```
@keyframes fTJakOHn_fade {
  0% { stroke-opacity:1; }
  94.44444444444444% { stroke-opacity:1; stroke-dasharray: none; }
  100% { stroke-opacity:0; stroke-dasharray:930 932; }
}
```

Example:

```css
.fTJakOHn_0 {
  stroke-dasharray:930 932;
  stroke-dashoffset:931;
}

.start .fTJakOHn_0 {
  animation:fTJakOHn_draw 3000ms ease-in 0ms forwards;
}

@keyframes fTJakOHn_draw {
  99.9% { stroke-dashoffset:0; stroke-dasharray:930 932; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: none; }
}

@keyframes fTJakOHn_fade {
  0% { stroke-opacity:1; }
  94.44444444444444% { stroke-opacity:1; stroke-dasharray: none; }
  100% { stroke-opacity:0; stroke-dasharray:930 932; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 242.89 367.25" class="start" style=""><title>triangeltest</title>

<path style="fill:#fff;stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:15px" d="M121.44,23.89L10.38,359.75L232.51,359.75L121.44,23.89Z" class="fTJakOHn_0"></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! Elegant solution that is easy to implement in my workflow.

Comment: One question though: I get a little flicker if I scroll during the animation at the exact time it removes the dasharray. Is this avoidable? If not, it's no big deal :)

Comment: That's probably a quirk of the browser you are using.   You could try making it so that it is completely faded out before the dasharray is changed.  Ie. make it `99% { stroke-opacity: 0; ...`

Comment: The fading part is actually added from Vivus Instant and not something I am using. I am just drawing the shape and then keeping it displayed. But your answer still works :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's any easier way of doing this, the closest solution I found recently was using a clip path on the SVG itself. I've just stuck this on your codepen example as a tester:

```
svg {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 6.4%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

You may want to increase the stroke width if needed? It's not pretty, but it gets the result.

Comment: This works for me, visually. But I don't exactly understand what it does. I imagine I need to adjust this for different shapes in more complex animations? How did you go about deciding the percentages? Maybe it would be hard to do on more complex shapes and delayed animations?

Comment: All the clipping path is doing is saying 'don't show anything outside of this boundary' :) The percentages relate to the points of the path in relation to the viewbox, so relatively simple for basic shapes such as triangles, squares, etc. but it may be a touch more complicated for more complex shapes. Again, not sure if it's really all that suitable for animations but worth a look. 

These might help a bit :)
https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. The best thing would be to have some other solution so that it works the way it does in Firefox. I don't know why Chrome displays it differently?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be adding `stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round;` for the triangle:

```js
Layer_1.addEventListener("click",()=>{Layer_1.classList.toggle("start")})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:200px;}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 242.89 367.25" class="start" ><title>triangeltest</title>
  <path style="fill:#fff;stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:15px" d="M121.44,23.89L10.38,359.75L232.51,359.75L121.44,23.89Z" class="fTJakOHn_0"></path>
  <style data-made-with="vivus-instant">
    .fTJakOHn_0{
      stroke-dasharray:930;
      stroke-dashoffset:930;
      stroke-linecap:round;
      stroke-linejoin:round;
    }
    .start .fTJakOHn_0{
      animation:fTJakOHn_draw 3000ms ease-in 0ms forwards;
    }
    @keyframes fTJakOHn_draw{
      100%{stroke-dashoffset:0;}
    }</style> 
</svg>
```